# Plone Unified Installer missing Python

Tags: linux, python-2.7, plone, sles

I'm trying to install plone 4.3.4 on a SLES 11 SP3 64bit server via the Unified Installer. I've fullfilled all the dependencies listed in the readme.txt, but when I try to get the installer running with the command sudo ./install.sh --password=******* standalone I get the error message: which: no python2.7 in (/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin) Unable to find python2.7 on system exec path.

I find that rather strange as in the description of the unified installer it is said "The new Zope/Plone install will use its own copy of Python, and the Python installed by the Unified Installer will not replace your system's copy of Python. You may optionally use your system (or some other) Python, and the Unified Installer will use it without modifying it or your site libraries." on the Plone-Website.

So - what am I doing wrong???

I've just tried adding the parameter --build-python but had to find out that the libxml2-devel and libxslt-devel libraries that are available for SLES-11-SP-3 are sadly not up-to-date enough 2.7.6 instead of 2.7.8 and 1.1.24 instead of 1.1.26 respectively. So no joy there either. :-(

Is there any way to install the current version of plone on SLES 11 SP3 64bit?

Kate

Comment: The `--build-python` parameter you added is the answer (in last few years the default is to use system Python).

So: you need to find a way to build manually libxml2-devel and libxslt-devel I think.

Answer (score 4):

The installer command:

> ./install.sh standalone --build-python --static-lxml=yes

worked perfectly for me. The installer downloaded and built the Python and libxml2/libxslt components necessary to remedy the terribly out-of-date (and vulnerable) versions included with sles11sp3.

System packages needed for the build were:

- gcc-c++
- make
- readline-devel
- libjpeg-devel
- zlib-devel
- patch
- libopenssl-devel
- libexpat-devel
- man

All installed via zypper.

I'd advise not using `sudo` for the install. If you want to, you'll need to create the plone_daemon and plone_buildout users and the plone_group group in advance due to oddities in SUSE's `adduser` implementation.

Comment: Thank you for the tipp. With all that information I finally got it to work as well. :-)